# Using filter to add additional fields to comment_form()

Tags: comments, filters, forms, comment-form

I want to add a field to the comments and have used these codes.

**functions.php**

```
function my_fields($fields) {
    $fields['url2'] = '<p class="comment-form-url2">
                          <label for="url2">URL hittad på webben</label>
                          <input id="url2" name="url2" type="text" value="" size="30" />
                       </p>';
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');
```

**comments.php**

```
comment_form();
```

**Questions**

1. It does not add an extra field in admin comment. Should it, or not?
2. It does not seem to save the extra field. I tried to var dump the comment array. Why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple other hooks in the comment form that you can use.  Where you're hooking on only displays if the user isn't logged in.  If you want that field for all users (logged in or not), you need to add your form by hooking into both `comment_form_after_fields` and `comment_form_logged_in_after`, both of which are actions, and echo out the new field.

```
<?php
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'pmg_comment_tut_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'pmg_comment_tut_fields' );
function pmg_comment_tut_fields()
{
    ?>
    <p class="comment-form-title">
        <label for="pmg_comment_title"><?php _e( 'Title' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="pmg_comment_title" id="pmg_comment_title" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Check out [this tutorial](http://pmg.co/adding-extra-fields-to-wordpress-comments) I wrote (the example above is from it).  Covers everything from adding fields to saving the data to adding a meta box so you can edit the extra fields on the back end too.

Comment: Can I ask what jquery lightbox plugin you're using on your site?

Comment: Which site, the one linked above or another?  It's probably Lightbox 3, but I can't find that one in the WP.org repo any more.

Comment: Your tutorial. Also, regarding the tutorial, you reference the comment title as $title in Part 2. How does the title from part 1 become $title?

Comment: Oh I see, nevermind.

Answer (score 5):

To save your extra field, you have to do :

```
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'extra_field', $_POST[ 'extra_field' ] );
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
```

See [this nice tutorial](http://wpengineer.com/2214/adding-input-fields-to-the-comment-form/) covering extra fields in comment forms.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin 
http://www.solaceten.info

(disclosure: I'm the co-author. The plugin is free, but not maintained any longer)

Comment: [You must disclose your affiliation in your answers.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)